# How to add a new serie using teechart?

Tags: java, teechart

This is where I take the signals to show them on the graph, the problem is that they aren't printed. I have been reading the use of the teechar library and I find no problem. Do you see if any part of the code is missing?

```
            grafica.addSerie("serieName", null);
            grafica.setSerieVisible(index, true);
            grafica.setAutoRange(false, index);
            grafica.setColorSerie(COLOR.Red, index);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is add your new serie data:

```
grafica.addSerie(ARRAY_AXIS_X_GET_VALUE, ARRAY_AXIS_X_GET_VALUE, YOUR_SERIE_INDEX);
```

Do not forget to iterate your data.